# Localization algorithm in the maze

Tags: algorithm

There is a maze with thick walls. The dimensions of the maze are known: length - 8, width - 8 .

[What are "thick walls" and "thin".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm6Lu.png)

In the labyrinth is a robot with several range sensors. The location of the robot is unknown. The location of the walls in the maze is also unknown. The challenge is to come up with an algorithm to quickly map the maze and determine the coordinates of the robot.

So far, I have come up with only two algorithms, but they are not optimal.
1) Move according to the rule of the right hand and remember all the walls. (This is a long time and if there is a cycle in the labyrinth, then the algorithm will not work)
2) Search the boundaries of the maze (also takes a lot of time and does not always work)

Please tell me the optimal algorithm that will work in all cases and will be relatively fast.

Answer (score 0):

So:

1. From any cell, you can determine which adjacent cells are passable; and
2. The robot can remember everything it discovers
3. The robot has to walk between adjacent cells.  It can't teleport to a faraway previously seen location.

Given (1) and (2), you can use any graph traversal algorithm to discover/map all the passable cells in the maze.  The passable cells are the nodes of the graph, with edges that connect them to the adjacent passable cells.

Because of (3), you need to use an algorithm that moves the search one square at a time instead of jumping all over the place.

Depth-first search is the appropriate way.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Note that this assumes that you actually have to visit all or most cells to determine which adjacent cells are open.  This assumption is invalid if your maze consists mainly of big open spaces (i.e., it's not very maze-like) *and* your range sensors can see walls that are many cells away.